# Draw same lines drawn on a Tkinter Canvas on an OpenCV image

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, mouseevent

Using the mouse, I let the user to draw random curves on a Tkinter Canvas. These curves are drawn as short lines between points over which the mouse moves.

My aim is to save the points used to draw the lines on the Canvas and to draw the same curves using the same points on a simple OpenCV window.

The drawing on the Canvas works perfectly, however, wherever I place the OpenCV window I never succeed to fulfill my goal. I think the problem may be in a wrong functions call order?

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2

class Test:
   def __init__(self):
       self.b1="up"
       self.xold=None
       self.yold=None
       self.liste=[]
   def test(self,obj):
       self.drawingArea=Canvas(obj)
       self.drawingArea.pack() 
       self.drawingArea.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
       self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.b1down)
       self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.b1up)
   def b1down(self,event):
       self.b1="down"
   def b1up(self,event):
       self.b1="up"
       self.xold=None
       self.yold=None
   def motion(self,event):
       if self.b1=="down":
           if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
               event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,fill="red",width=3,smooth=TRUE)
           self.xold=event.x
           self.yold=event.y
           self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))
       self.MC=MaClasse()
       self.MC.dessiner_lignes()
       self.MC.maclasse()
   def get_points(self):
       for i in range(len(self.liste)):
           print self.liste[i]
       return self.liste
class MaClasse:
   def __init__(self):   
       self.s=600,600,3
       self.les_points=[]# Empty list
       self.ma=np.zeros(self.s,dtype=np.uint8)
   def maclasse(self):
       cv2.namedWindow("OpenCV",cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
       cv2.imshow("OpenCV",self.ma)
       cv2.waitKey(0)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
   def dessiner_lignes(self):
       self.voi=Test()
       self.les_points=self.voi.get_points()
       # It always displays 0
       print "number of points: {}".format(len(self.les_points))
       for i in range(len(self.les_points)):
           print i
           if i<len(self.les_points)-1:
               print self.les_points[i]
               self.first_point=self.les_points[i]
               self.second_point=self.les_points[i+1]
               cv2.line(self.ma,self.first_point,self.second_point,[255,255,255],2)

if __name__=="__main__":
   root=Tk()
   root.wm_title("Test")
   v=Test()
   v.test(root)
   root.mainloop()
   MC=MaClasse()
   v.get_points() # I get the points here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't create a `MaClasse` instance during the Motion event, since that way you create a new `MaClasse` every time a new line is drawn. You only want to create one `MaClasse` and get the points from `Test` into it. Therefore, you can completely separate `MaClasse` and `Test`.

You get the points using

```
root = Tk()
v = Test()
v.test(root)
root.mainloop()
points = v.get_points()
```

This sets up the `Test` app, and after all points have been drawn, uses `get_points()` to get the points.

Then, you can set up a `MaClasse` instance, but you need a way to pass the points into it. The most sensible way (to me) seems to be to pass them into the `dessiner_lignes` function, since that draws the lines. If you alter `dessiner_lignes` so that it accepts a `les_points` variable (`def dessiner_lignes(self, les_points=[]):`), you can then draw and show the image using

```
MC = MaClasse()
MC.dessiner_lignes(points)
MC.maclasse()
```

To separate separately drawn curves, you can place a `(None, None)` "coordinate" when the mouse button is released (so in `b1up`). Then in `dessiner_lignes` just check if both coordinates are not `(None, None)` before drawing the line segment.

---

Your complete code then looks like this. Note that I've also removed `self` from `les_points`, `first_point` and `second_point` in `dessiner_lignes` since they are only used in that method, so there is no need to save them as class attributes.

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste=[]
    def test(self,obj):
        self.drawingArea=Canvas(obj)
        self.drawingArea.pack() 
        self.drawingArea.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.b1down)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.b1up)
    def b1down(self,event):
        self.b1="down"
    def b1up(self,event):
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))
    def motion(self,event):
        if self.b1=="down":
            if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,fill="red",width=3,smooth=TRUE)
            self.xold=event.x
            self.yold=event.y
            self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))
    def get_points(self):
        #for i in range(len(self.liste)):
            #print self.liste[i]
        return self.liste

class MaClasse:
    def __init__(self):   
        self.s=600,600,3
        self.ma=np.zeros(self.s,dtype=np.uint8)
    def maclasse(self):
        cv2.namedWindow("OpenCV",cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV",self.ma)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    def dessiner_lignes(self, les_points=[]):
        print "number of points: {}".format(len(les_points))
        for i in range(len(les_points)):
            #print i
            if i<len(les_points)-1:
                #print les_points[i]
                first_point=les_points[i]
                second_point=les_points[i+1]
                if not first_point == (None, None) and not second_point == (None, None):
                    cv2.line(self.ma,first_point,second_point,[255,255,255],2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Test")
    v = Test()
    v.test(root)
    root.mainloop()
    points = v.get_points()

    MC = MaClasse()
    MC.dessiner_lignes(points)
    MC.maclasse()
```

Comment: Yes, you are right about removing `self` from those 2 attributes. Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, the advantage of separating `Test` and `MaClasse` and passing the points into `dessiner_lignes` is that you can call `dessiner_lignes` more than once if you might have points from multiple instances of `Test`. So you can run the `root=Tk() ... points=v.get_points()` part twice (assigning to `points2 ` the second time for instance) and then you only need an extra call to `dessiner_lignes(points2)` to draw the lines from both `Test` instances.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again but I found a problem in our program :( let's say I draw 2 separate curves/segments on the Canvas: they look always unified on the OpenCV window :( I do not know which condition to check in order not link every 2 consecutive points unless if they are previously linked on the Canvas

Comment: Ah right. You could solve this by placing `(None, None)` at a break (so at a `b1up` event). Then you can ignore any line segments in the OpenCV drawing that have coordinates that are None. I'll update the answer to include this.