# Displaying TkInter and OpenCV windows on the same time

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am working to extend this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185235/draw-same-lines-drawn-on-a-tkinter-canvas-on-an-opencv-image/30187144#30187144) given to me previously.

The user can draw randomly using the mouse on a TkInter Canvas widget, after that, the same curves with the same pixels coordinates are drawn on the OpenCV window.

I want to modify that solution so that the TkInter Canvas and the OpenCV window must be shown in the same time: each time the suer finishes drawing one curve on TkInter it is immediately redrawn on the OpenCV window.

Is there a way to fulfill this goal ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is arguably even easier to do than to draw all lines in OpenCV later.

I'd make the `MaClasse` class only make a blank image, open a window and show it on initiation, and give it a method to draw a single line and show the image again.Then you can create a `MaClasse` object in `Test` and draw a line in OpenCV each time you draw a line in Tkinter. Then you won't even need to save all lines you've drawn (you can completely remove `self.liste`).

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste=[]
        self.maclasse = MaClasse()
    def test(self,obj):
        self.drawingArea=Canvas(obj)
        self.drawingArea.pack() 
        self.drawingArea.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.b1down)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.b1up)
    def b1down(self,event):
        self.b1="down"
    def b1up(self,event):
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))
    def motion(self,event):
        if self.b1=="down":
            if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,fill="red",width=3,smooth=TRUE)
                self.maclasse.dessiner_ligne(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y)
            self.xold=event.x
            self.yold=event.y
            self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))

class MaClasse:
    def __init__(self):   
        self.s=600,600,3
        self.ma=np.zeros(self.s,dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.namedWindow("OpenCV",cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV",self.ma)

    def dessiner_ligne(self, xold, yold, x, y):
        cv2.line(self.ma,(xold, yold),(x,y),[255,255,255],2)
        cv2.imshow("OpenCV",self.ma)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Test")
    v = Test()
    v.test(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

---

Since the above code using a Tkinter window and a OpenCV window does not work for you, you could also show the OpenCV image in a Tkinter Toplevel window.

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Image, ImageTk

class Test:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste=[]
        self.maclasse = MaClasse(self.parent)
    def test(self):
        self.drawingArea=Canvas(self.parent)
        self.drawingArea.pack() 
        self.drawingArea.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.b1down)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.b1up)
    def b1down(self,event):
        self.b1="down"
    def b1up(self,event):
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))
    def motion(self,event):
        if self.b1=="down":
            if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,fill="red",width=3,smooth=TRUE)
                self.maclasse.dessiner_ligne(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y)
            self.xold=event.x
            self.yold=event.y
            self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))

class MaClasse:
    def __init__(self, parent):   
        self.s=600,600,3
        self.ma=np.zeros(self.s,dtype=np.uint8)
        self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        self.top.wm_title("OpenCV Image")
        self.label = Label(self.top)
        self.label.pack()
        self.show_image()

    def dessiner_ligne(self, xold, yold, x, y):
        cv2.line(self.ma,(xold, yold),(x,y),[255,255,255],2)
        self.show_image()

    def show_image(self):
        self.im = Image.fromarray(self.ma)
        self.imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.im)
        self.label.config(image=self.imgtk)


if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Test")
    v = Test(root)
    v.test()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. But the OpenCV window is never displayed (no errors). I try to read again your code

Comment: That's weird, when you literally copy this code and run it, do you not see an OpenCV window?

Comment: I copy/past your code yes. No modification but only TkInter window is displayed. I think it is displayed but it disappears quickly so the human eye can not see it. I tried to add an event to wait (`cv2.waitKey()`) but it blocks me

Comment: I don't see why it should close. `cv2.waitkey` does block further execution so you shouldn't use that. You could try to show the OpenCV image in a Tkinter Toplevel window though, let me try to make an example doing that.

Comment: Just to try and find what's introducing the difference between what you and I see, what version of OpenCV  (`print cv2.__version__`), Tkinter (`print Tkinter.__version__`) and Pyhton (`print sys.version`) do you use?

Comment: Opencv: `3.0.0-beta`. TkInter: `81008`

Comment: The second approach works just fine.  You are studying medical natural sciences, so I do not understand why you are smart in programming. Thank you very much.

Comment: Weird, I use OpenCV `3.0.0-rc` (which isn't all too different from the beta) and the same Tkinter, maybe it's OS related? I'm on Windows 7. But I'm glad you like the second approach too. It's clearly more fail-safe.

Comment: I  am using Ubuntu 14.04 instead.