# using of tkinter Trackbar and slider for OpenCV

Tags: python, tkinter

my Question:
How can I learn the using of the Trckbar from tkinter for OpenCV? With the trackbar i want edit my picture.

Please help me
Thank you

Comment: possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54420599/how-to-add-a-cv2-tracking-bar-in-a-tkinter-window

Comment: But I dont understand it. How can I get a manual?

Comment: What is a "Trckbar" or "Trackbar"? Tkinter doesn't have anything by that name.